# How can I inherit class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I create CSS style in notepad++ and I want to pass that style to visual studio CSS,
but it does not inherit as expected.
The inherited sign `>` does not match.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .flip3d {
        width: 240px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 10px;
        float: left;
    }
    .flip3d>.front {
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY( 0deg );
        transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
        background: #FC0;
        width: 240px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: -webkit-transform .9s linear 0s;
        transition: transform .9s linear 0s;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: _“the inherited sign ">" does not match”_ – that statement does not make any sense to me. `>` is the child selector, it has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with inheritance.

Comment: [Inheritance works](http://jsfiddle.net/tMX2Q/), what is your expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS classes do not have inheritance. But you can specify multiple classes in an element. If you wanted an element to use both "flip3d" and "flip3d_front", you could just specify it like this:

```
<div class="flip3d flip3d_front"></div>
```

"flip3d_front" will override any conflicting parent definitions given by "flip3d".

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how inheritance works in CSS. A CSS class doesn't inherit from a parent class. Rather a child element can inherit the styles of it's parent element.

What you've used above is the child selector and has nothing to do with inheritance. It simply says:

> apply this style to any children of an element with a class of
>   'flip3d' that has a class of front

If you want to re-use styles in the way that you're expecting, you'd have to use something like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Otherwise, what you want to do can be achieved through simply adding both classes to the element that you want to be styled that way (assuming that element is a child of an element that also has the `flip3d` class.